# How to change background color of my selector's Pseudo-element on rollover?

Tags: jquery, css, shapes, pseudo-element

**My CodePen:** http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/cfLEh

I have this 'pointy sign' button created from an exmaple on [CSS shapes](http://www.cssportal.com/css3-shapes/).

Basically the `arrow-button` has a background color and the `arrow-button:before` creates the background for the triangle on the right side of the box.

I would like to on hover or mouseenter change the background color of the entire shape from blue to orange.

[image]

How would you go about doing this?

The CSS

```css
#arrow-button {
   width: 120px; 
   height: 57px; 
   background: blue;
   position: relative;
   left: 200px;
   cursor: pointer;
}
#arrow-button:before {
   content:"";
   position: absolute;
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   border-top: 28.5px solid transparent;
   border-left: 10px solid blue;
   border-bottom: 28.5px solid transparent;
   margin: 0 15px 0 120px;
}
```

jQuery

```
$('#arrow-button').mouseenter( function(){
  $('#arrow-button')
     .css(
      'background', 
      '#fc8236');
  $('#arrow-button:before')
    .css(
       'border-left', 
      '10px solid #fc8236');
});

$('#arrow-button').mouseleave( function(){
  $('#arrow-button')
    .css(
      'background', 
      'blue');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no need for js at all:

```
#arrow-button {
   width: 120px; 
   height: 57px; 
   background: blue;
   position: relative;
   left: 200px;
   cursor: pointer;
}
#arrow-button:before {
   content:"";
   position: absolute;
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   border-top: 28.5px solid transparent;
   border-left: 10px solid blue;
   border-bottom: 28.5px solid transparent;
   margin: 0 15px 0 120px;
}

#arrow-button:hover {
   background: orange;
}

#arrow-button:hover:before {

  content:"";
   position: absolute;
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   border-top: 28.5px solid transparent;
   border-left: 10px solid orange;
   border-bottom: 28.5px solid transparent;
   margin: 0 15px 0 120px;

}
```

Comment: Oh sweet, thanks! I didn't know you could chain them like that :) .. 7 more mins

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using *css* only:

```
#arrow-button:hover {
   width: 180px; 
   height: 57px; 
   background: #fc8236;
   position: relative;
   left: 200px;
   text-align: center;
   cursor: pointer;
}

#arrow-button:hover:before {
   content:"";
   position: absolute;
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   border-top: 28.5px solid transparent;
   border-left: 10px solid #fc8236;
   border-bottom: 28.5px solid transparent;
   margin: 0 15px 0 134px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could attach a class to `#arrow-button` that updates the border color of the `:before` pseudo-element:

**CSS**

```
#arrow-button.orange {
  background-color: #fc8236;
}

#arrow-button.orange:before {
  border-left: 10px solid #fc8236;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#arrow-button').mouseenter( function(){
  $('#arrow-button').addClass('orange');
});

$('#arrow-button').mouseleave( function(){
  $('#arrow-button').removeClass('orange');
});
```